# How to build a Liferay project of both portlet and hook types

Tags: eclipse, ant, liferay, hook, liferay-ide

I have a Liferay project that was originally created as a portlet type (i.e., under `${Liferay plugin SDK folder}/portlets`).  Later on, it became essentially a hook type also as JSP overrides and such were added.  When I tried to build the project by running `ant compile`, I got errors like `The import com.liferay.portal.util.CookieKeys cannot be resolved`.  I don't get this error when the project is compiled in the Liferay IDE which is able to recognize Liferay projects of mixed types.  I was wondering if there is anyone here who has had experience with compilation such Liferay projects from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your build.${username}.properties at the root of your `${Liferay plugin SDK folder}` has the following settings:

```
app.server.type = tomcat
app.server.dir = /path/to/tomcat
```

Then you should be able to re-compile from command line.  The reason it works in Liferay IDE is that it adds compile dependencies to your project automatically if you have specified a Liferay Tomcat runtime.